# how to query specific fields in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

I need to fetch only specific feilds instead of all fields. All my tables has audit feilds(4) . i want that to be ommitted on the selection. how to do that from mapping. is there any other way?.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Property.class, "property")
                .createAlias("property.propertyType", "type").createAlias(
                        "property.propertyConcern", "propertyConcern",
                        CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN).createAlias(
                        "propertyConcern.concern", "concern",
                        CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
                        .setResultTransformer(
                        CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ProjectionList](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/criterion/ProjectionList.html) to return only the fields you are after.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Property.class, "property")
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("property.field1"))
        .add(Projections.property("concern.field2"))
        /*etc*/)
    /*etc etc etc*/;
```

The result is an array of arrays.

```
for (Object result : criteria.list()) {
    final Object[] fields = (Object[]) result;
    log.info("property.field1={}, concern.field2={}", fields[0], fields[1]);
}
```

By the way, your entity name "Property" could cause confusion/conflict with the existing Hibernate class, especially since you are using Criteria.

Comment: But, Again i need to iterate into returned items to form object hierachy. instead of that is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Transformers.aliasToBean(Property.class)`..

```
ProjectionList properties = Projections.projectionList();
properties.add(Projections.property("p.id"), "id");//"id" should match with the property name to call setters
properties.add(Projections.property("p.fname"), "fname");
properties.add(Projections.property("s.lname"), "lname");


criteria.setProjection(properties);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Student.class));
List<Student> students = (List<Student>) criteria.list();
```